# Symfony Encore: Cannot determine webpack context. (Are you executing webpack from a directory outside of your project?)

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

I've just installed Encore to test it and start using it in my projects (great great work!!! Really, thank you!).

I'm immediately having an issue.

When trying to run `./node_modules/.bin/encore dev` I receive the exception:

> Cannot determine webpack context. (Are you executing webpack from a directory outside of your project?). Try passing the --context option.

I've simply followed the instructions in the [official documentation about the first example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) and the result is this exception.

My project is structured like so:

```
my-app-root-folder
- app
- bin
- nome_modules
- src
- tests
- var
- vendor
- web
...
composer.json
composer.lock
webpack.config.js
```

So, basically, I have the classical structure of a Symfony 3.3 project, plus some folders related to `JS`.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

This is the very first time I approach a more sophisticated solution to manage css and javascript assets.

Unitl now I've done all putting those files in `src/AppBundle/Resources/public/` so I'm not very experienced with this new flow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that I din't run `npm init` and then `npm install`.

The library requires a `package.json` file that is created by npm.

More info [here](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/82#issuecomment-313364151).